# Не загружаются куки на сайт wax'а

Tags: python, selenium, бот, браузер

Я хотел входить на сайт крипто-кошелька wax через куки, загрузил их в файлик и в коде пытался загрузить, но вылетает непонятная мне ошибка. Пробовал всё тоже самое с вк и всё работало. Кто знает, что делать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]g

Comment: На зтом сайте картинки не приветсвуются.

Comment: укажите какая ошибка

Comment: Ошибка на скрине